# iOS 11 Takes Tons of Storage

Tags: storage, bug, ios

Storage shows that *System* takes about 12 Gb of storage.

Anyone else have System taking up 12 GB after installing, and know how to fix it?

Edit: storage taken up by system keeps rising. Reaching 13 GB.

[image: Screenshot]

> iPhone SE.
>   Restart didn't help.

Comment: I have the same issue on my phone. Unfortunately, I cannot update to the latest update, because even after deleting all of my apps, I still don't have enough space. I don't know the solution to this problem, but at least you know it's not only you.

Comment: @JosephL ,  Pls Try this , Settings-> Safari-> "Clear history and Website Data" then reboot your device

Comment: Since you have pother breakage - news app, I would say you likely just got a bad build / beta issue and a clean wipe will make you much happier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple triage - the “system” either now contains an iOS update cached or a lot of user data, but you can convince yourself:

1. Backup the device
2. Erase all content and settings

Measure the space. If you feel it’s still taking a lot of space, put the device in recovery mode and restore it.

Once you’re OK with the space usage of the bare system, erase one more time and restore from your backup of choice or just sign in and set it up new if you want to start fresh.